# Масштабирование картинки в блоке

Tags: html, css, изображения

вопрос как вместить картинку на всю высоту блока? Размеры блока:460х451, картинки: 458х445. Вот мои стили:

```
.image-box{
  position: relative;
  border:1px solid white;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 8px rgba(27,20,100,0.15);
  margin-top:-50px;
  left:30px;
  margin-bottom:50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.image{
  object-fit: cover;
  max-height:460px;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Делать через background-image не вариант.

Comment: display: block картинке

Comment: вроде до этого пробовал - не получалось, но сейчас работает, спасибо!